# Ajax Post Hitting Success But Not Hitting VB.Net Function

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, vb.net

I've read over a few other questions but still can't find the answer to my specific question.  I am trying to call a vb.net sub with an Ajax Post.  The ajax function is hitting the success but never hitting my breakpoints in my sub or actually inserting into my database.  Any help is appreciated.

aspx.vb

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub insertKPI(id As String)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SqlServerConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "kpi_InsertKPI"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartnerLinkCode", HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("partnerlinkcode").ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserLinkCode", HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("userlinkcode").ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KPIInfoLinkCode", id)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Script

```
function addWidget(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../secure/scorecardtable.aspx/insertKPI",
        data: '{"id":' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}',
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(result){
            alert("New kpi should be in database");
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("There was an error inserting the kpi into the database.  " + xhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }); // End Ajax
}
```

Comment: Create `.asmx` web service or WCF service (`.svc`). Web pages usually don't process ajax requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `contentType` to my ajax function actually made it work.

```
function addWidget(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../secure/scorecardtable.aspx/insertKPI",
        data: '{"id":' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(result){
            alert("New kpi should be in database");
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("There was an error inserting the kpi into the database.  " + xhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }); // End Ajax
}
```